# Why does using an implicit collection initializer for dictionaries cause a runtime error in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an async method with the following signiature:

```
public async Task UpdateMerchantAttributes(UpdateMerchantRequestModel model).
```

The model only has one property:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
```

For a while I was calling it in a test in the following way:

```
await client.UpdateMerchantAttributes(new UpdateMerchantRequestModel { Attributes = 
    {
        {"businessType", "0"}
    }
});
```

This compiled just fine, but caused a `NullReferenceException` at runtime on that line. I was confused about this because `client` was not null, and nothing else is referenced in that line (or so it seems at a glance). Then I tried adding an explicit Dictionary declaration, like so:

```
await client.UpdateMerchantAttributes(new UpdateMerchantRequestModel { Attributes =
    new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"businessType", "0"}
    }
});
```

And now it passes fine. It was my mistake, but this mistake would've cost me much less time if it'd been a compile error rather than a runtime null ref exception. So I'm curious, why does this happen? Does the compiler think that I'm trying to define a `dynamic` and that somehow resolves to `null`?

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure why you *wouldn't* expect it to be a runtime error. It is no different than any other.

Comment: @mjwills - You might as well just post that as an answer.

Comment: tip: `public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; } = new Dictionary<string,string>();` - concise and convenient (and fixes the problem, which is for exactly the reasons that @mjwills notes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first form:

```
Attributes = 
    {
        {"businessType", "0"}
    }
}
```

is [syntactic sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) for `.Add(key, value)`. That is all. It isn't concerned with creating the dictionary (so, in effect, you are adding to a `null` dictionary).

Your second form is one way to solve it. Another, slightly more bulletproof way (since it protects you against the first form), is to use @MarcGravell's suggestion:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes
    { get; } = new Dictionary<string,string>(); // set; after the get; is also OK
```

or to populate `Attributes` in the constructor.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So without `new` it's an implied add. Makes sense. Thanks so much

Comment: With, or without, the `new` it is an implied add @Jansky .